# Html5 page sliding issues

Tags: javascript, html

This code below works by sliding the content of DIV but what i want is if user is on the first page and click on the links, it will slide him to second page in full and vice versa.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Page Slide

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
  var w = $(window).width();
  var h = $(window).height();
  var slides = $('.Slides > div');
  $('.SlideContainer').css({ height: (h-60) + 'px' });
  $('.Slides').css({ width: slides.length + '00%' });
  slides.css({ width: w + 'px' });

  var pos = 0;

  $('.Left').click(function(){
    pos--;
    $('.Slides').animate({ left: (pos * w) + 'px' });
  });
  $('.Right').click(function(){
    pos++;
    $('.Slides').animate({ left: (pos * w) + 'px' });
  });

});

</script>

<style type="text/css">

body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.Header { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; background: #000; color: #fff; }
.Footer { position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; background: #000; color: #fff; }

.SlideContainer { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 30px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
.Slides { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; height: 100%; }
.Slides > div { float: left; height: 100%; overflow: scroll; }

.Slides .Content { margin-top: 100px; text-align: center; }
.Slides .Content a { font-size: 30px; }

</style>

</head>
<body>


<div class="SlideContainer">
  <div class="Slides">

    <div class="Slide">
      <div class="Content">
        <h1>I am on the First Page</h1>
        <a href="secondpage.html" class="Left">Slide Me to Secondpage</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Slide">
      <div class="Content">
        <h1>I am on the second page</h1>
        <a href="firstpage.html" class="Left">Slide Me back to First Page</a>

      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you do is when the user wants to go to page 2 you make an Ajax call to render page 2 and place it into the div off-screen, then slide, remove the previous page (or leave it in case they go back) and add a new div on the right. The only downside to this is that since you are not creating a postback you would probably have to maintain your own history and intercept the back button.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your redirecting the page, your going to have to take whatever you have on the secondPage.html and basically make one long page for your webpage through css so when you click to slide to the next page, it slides instead of redirects you.

Or make a few Ajax calls as what @Christopher White is saying. (saves you from making a large page that takes long load times)

Ajax could go a little something like so:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/test2.html',
    type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
    dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
    //Put your go to page function here ie switch to page 2 
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
    //something went wrong, what should it do?
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
    //This will ALWAYS happen whether you get a failure or a success
});
```

Check out http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for some prime examples and uses/explanations on ajax calls.

Comment: can you provide an example of this with ajax call

Comment: I'll post an example ajax into my edited answer (sorry for the late reply I got really busy last night)

Comment: Would you be so kind as to select an answer for this question? Thanks! The site appreciates it!